# Updating single image in array replace all images with updated image in media array image MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to upload a new image in place of an old one.

Now I am having multiple images while editing a single image: I am passing object id, item id and old_file name from .ts file to the service file then service file to API.

Currently while uploading the file it replaces old media image with the new image but replaces media array within mongoose with single file uploaded.

#### moongose media array:

```
"media_data" : [ 
  "1531126685017_Fri Nov 03 2017 12_05_42 GMT+0530 (IST)_test.jpg", 
  "1531126705706_Fri Nov 03 2017 12_45_52 GMT+0530 (IST)_swolemate.PNG", 
  "1531126714516_Fri Nov 03 2017 12_40_52 GMT+0530 (IST)_Sprint.png"
],
```

#### api code:

```
router.post('/updateMedia', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
  var postid = req.body.postId;
  var userid = req.body.userId;
  var mediaid = req.body.itemId;
  var oldfilename = req.body.oldfile;
  console.log(oldfilename);
  //console.log(oldfilename);
  var files = req.files;
  var length = req.files.length;
  var extensions = ['.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.mov', '.mp4', '.mkv', '.avi', '.webm'];
  for (var media = 0; media < length; media++) {
    var file = files[media].filename;
    var ext = path.extname(files[media].filename);
    var newMedia = new Media();
    newMedia.media = file;
    newMedia.user_id = userid;
    newMedia.post_id = postid;
    newMedia.update(function(err, dataId) {
      Post.updateOne({
          _id: postid
        }, {
          "media_data": file
        }, {
          $addToSet: {
            "media_data.$": oldfilename
          }

        })
        .exec(function(err, posts) {
          if (posts) {
            res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              message: "updated successfully.",
              status: 200
            });
          } else {
            res.status(500).json({
              success: false,
              message: "Internal error occurred.",
              status: 500

            })
          }
        });
    });
  }
});
```

#### html code:

```
<input id="file" multiple (change)="editMediaItems(post.id,mediaFile.itemId,mediaFile.post,$event, i)" type="file">
```

#### ts code:

```
upload_media(data): Observable<any>{    
  let newdata = new FormData();
  newdata.append('postId', data.postId);
  newdata.append('userId', data.id);
  newdata.append('itemId', data.itemId);
  newdata.append('upload_file', data.upload_file);  
  newdata.append('oldfile', data.oldfile);      
  let url = this.api_url.concat('updateMedia');
  return this.http.post(url, newdata ).map(response => response);
}
```

Comment: Because of this   `{
          "media_data": file
        }`. you can use $push

Comment: while using $push it adding new element with in array i want to replace old file with new file without affecting old array

Comment: Then you have to find and replace the file with the new file. and the set the array in the media_data